# List partition for remaining items

Tags: mysql, oracle

when partitioning tables in MySQL using a list, how can I generate a partition for remaining items?

E.G:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
 ID integer
)
PARTITION BY LIST (ID)
(  
  PARTITION P1 values in (1),  
  PARTITION P2 values in (2),  
  PARTITION P3 values in (3),  
  PARTITION Pother values in (<all remaining values of ID>)
);
```

In Oracle, I use `values in (default)`, but that does work in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike [range partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html), there is no "catch-all" in [list partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html). To quote the documentation:

> Unlike the case with RANGE partitioning, there is no “catch-all” such
>   as MAXVALUE; all expected values for the partitioning expression
>   should be covered in PARTITION ... VALUES IN (...) clauses. An INSERT
>   statement containing an unmatched partitioning column value fails with
>   an error...

Unfortunately, I believe, you're not able to combine a list and a range partition either. I'm not entirely certain why you would want to use a list partition in this particular instance; wouldn't a range partition work just a well?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
 ID integer
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (ID)
(  
  PARTITION P1 values less than (2),  
  PARTITION P2 values less than (3),  
  PARTITION P3 values less than (4),  
  PARTITION Pother values less than maxvalue
);
```

I'm assuming that this is just an example. Partitioning each key in a primary key is a little pointless.

Comment: Thanks @LenielMacaferi, it appears as though SQL Fiddle is a little bit broken at the moment...

Comment: Changed the MySQL version in the SQL Fiddle. See if it works now... :) Here it's working.

Answer (score 0):

A side note to consider if you are using `varchar` values in your list. You will have to resort to using the `IGNORE` identifier in your `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_names VALUES ..... ;
```

This will go ahead and ignore the error but display a warning.
can be found in 8.0+ documentation [MYSQL Site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/partitioning-list.html)